# Tantra way of Bhuta Shuddhi

Tags: tantra

Which Tantra talks of Bhuta shuddhi sadhana? What are the steps involved in it?

Also what is the ultimate goal of this particular sadhana?

Comment: In Tantra, it's a sin to reveal the methods/steps of sadhana.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Various Tantras talk about BhutaShuddhi. As it is an essential purification ritual to be performed by an aspirant before starting the worship.

Lord Sadashiva says the following verses in Chapter 5 of the Mahanirvana Tantram:

> The wise worshipper should place the articles necessary for worship on
> his right, and scented water and other Kula articles on his left (89).
> Saying the Mula−mantra terminated by the Weapon−Mantra, let him take
> water from the common offering and sprinkle the articles of worship
> with it, and then enclose himself and the articles in a circle of
> water. After that, O Devi! let him by the Vahni Vija surround them
> with a wall of fire (90). Then for the purification of the palms of
> his hands he should take up a flower which has been dipped in sandal
> paste, rub it between the palms, reciting meanwhile the Mantra Phat,
> and throw it away (91). Then in the following manner let him fence all
> the quarters so that no obstructions proceed from them. Join the first
> and second fingers of the right hand, and tap the palm of the left
> hand three times, each time after the first with greater force, thus
> making a loud sound, and then snap the fingers while uttering the
> weapon−Mantra (92).
> **He should then proceed to perform the purification of the elements of his body**. The excellent disciple should place his hands in his
> lap with the palms upwards, and fixing his mind on the Muladhara
> Chakra let him rouse Kundalini by uttering the Vija "Hung." Having so
> roused Her, let him lead Her with Prithivi by means of the Hangsa
> Mantra to the Svadhishthana Chakra, and let him there dissolve each
> one of the elements of the body by means of another of such elements
> (93−94). Then let him dissolve Prithivi together with odour, as also
> the organ of smell, into water. Dissolve water and taste, as also the
> sense of taste itself, into Fire (95). Dissolve Fire and vision and
> form, and the sense of sight itself, into air (96)

"He should then proceed to perform the purification of the elements of his body" --- Here "purification of the elements of the body" is nothing but Bhuta Shuddhi.

In Hinduism, creation starts from Brahman and then evolves to Prakriti then to Mahat etc. till the Pancha Bhutas (the five primordial elements Jala, Agni, Vayu and two others). In Bhutashuddhi the disciple reverses the process of creation, performs an involution starting from the Pancha Bhutas. The elements are successively dissolved (by use of specific Mantras) in the preceding elements till Brahman. So the idea is to perform the worship after becoming Brahman oneself.

Other scriptures also describe the Bhuta Shuddhi process. The Sri Vidya manual Nityotsava also has detailed the process using various Sri Vidya Mula mantras.